# jQuery is not finding elements

Tags: jquery, selector

jQuery is not finding any elements. `alert($("#testbutton").length);` displays 0 every time.

Am I doing something wrong?

**My JS / jQuery code:**

```
(function ($) {
    alert($("#testbutton").length);
}) (jQuery);
```

**My HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="button" id="testbutton">Test</div>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works just find in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2CX2y/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your code runs the DOM is not ready so the element doesn't exist. Did you mean to do this instead (passing a function to jQuery is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(fn)`):

```
$(function () {
    alert($("#testbutton").length);
});
```

Comment: (function ($) {
})(jQuery); is equivalent to $(function(){});

Comment: @InternalServerError - No it's not. It's just an immediately executed function expression that passes in the `jQuery` object. The 2nd is completely different - passing a function to jQuery.

Comment: I don't believe that's the case; the first is an IIFE that simply passes the `jQuery` variable to the function being executed; the second is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 2):

If you write jQuery script in the head using:

```
(function() {

    ...

})();
```

it doesn't work because it may execute the script before loading the content of the body page.

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    ...

});
```

or move your script at the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Call it on document ready as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/SwQUH/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("#testbutton").length);
});
```

If you just call it like that, the DOM isn't 'ready' and the HTML element doesnt yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

And first ensure thers no error in loading jquery

put an alert on load of DOM and check if everything is fine.