# TypeError: audio[0].addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to recreate [this HTML5 player](http://jsfiddle.net/lastrose/vkMqR/), but even if I copy/paste the code, I still get errors.

The first error I fixed by changeing `audio[0].volume = .10;` to this  `audio[0]  = { volume : .10 };`

But this next one I can't fix: `audio[0].addEventListener("ended",function(e){`

So now, when I click another tracktitle it just opens the url :(

The Fiddle works fine! http://jsfiddle.net/lastrose/vkMqR/

Can anyone help??

Comment: I would guess that the error shown for `audio[0].volume = .10;` was that you cant set `volume` for `undefined`, is that correct. With `audio[0]  = { volume : .10 };` you set `auto[0]` to an object, as of that this one does not have a function `addEventListener`.

Comment: Errors in fiddle code here you don't need to add index in `run()` for `audio[0].load();audio[0].play();` just is required `audio.load();audio.play();` because we passed `audio[0]` to function;

Comment: @t.niese correct, but do you mean that that was wrong? or should I have done the same for addEventListener ?

Comment: No the `audio[0] = { volume : .10 };` itself is wrong. It has to be `audio[0].volume = .10;`. At the time you call `init` the `audio` is not in the DOM. You need to load your script either at the end of the `body` or use the dom ready event ([Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959) ,  [jQuery is not finding elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301605)).

Comment: @t.niese moved the script after the HTML5 code, and it worked perfectly :D Thanks

Comment: Don't know if I should create a new thread, but can you also help me start autoplay when the page is loaded?

Comment: @MadsRH Your really should do a search before asking:  [Playing audio after the page loads in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356956)