# $(button).click(function() not working when javascript in on the top of jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble on dealing with $(button).click(function) in javascript.

Everything has worked fine when I put javascript code which is laid between script tag on the bottom of the page (below html code).

But when I put the code above html code, the function never works.

The other codes works fine. 
That is, only the function is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery is not finding elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301605/jquery-is-not-finding-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you write `<script>` code above `html code button` was not created and your script will run first so no any output given

so you need to use

```
$(document).ready()
```

so after page properly load then script will run so work properly

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      console.log('work');
    });
  });
</script>


<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because its trying to find the button element before the html has loaded.

Wrap it in a `$( document ).ready(function(){...})` function block so that it waits till the DOM has loaded before executing